# Cannot use thread constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've been trying to learn how to multi thread, but I could not the thread object to create properly. I have an object with a function called task, but when I add the function and the argument, it says the constructor doesn't take it. Btw im using visual studio as my IDE.

Here is my main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "Task.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Task t;
    thread t1(t.task, 1);
    t1.join;
    return 0;
}
```

the class of the Task Object:

```
#include "Task.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Task::Task()
{
}
Task::~Task()
{
}
void Task::task(int x) {
    cout << "In Thread " << x << '\n';
}
```

The error:`Error: no instance of constructor"std::thread::thread" matches the argument list
argument types are: (<error-type>, int)`

Update:
So i put in `thread t1(&Task::task, &t, 1);` and got rid of `t1.join`, but now i have a new problem. The program compilers and runs, but right when it runs, it displays "In Thread 1" in console, and another window comes up that says:

```
Debug Error!

abort() has been called

(Press retry to debug the application)
```

Comment: Visual Studio _what_? There have been many versions.

Comment: `t1.join` won't compile, you should always try to post your real code instead of typing it in on the spot.

Comment: i am using visual studio professional 2015

Comment: I've edited to fix your other problem. You need to call `join` or else the tread will call `std::terminate` when it's destructor executes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have is that `Task::task` is a member function. Member functions have a hidden parameter that is used as the `this` pointer. To make that work you should pass an instance of the class to be used as the `this` pointer. So initialize your thread like this

```
thread t1(&Task::task, &t, 1)
```

The other problem you have in your example is that `join` isn't being called. `t.join` doesn't actually call `join`, you have to call it like this: `t.join()`. If the destructor of a `std::thread` executes and `join` hasn't been called the destructor will call `std::terminate`.

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) for more information on `std::thread`'s constructor and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) for its destructor.

Comment: i did that, but now i have a new error. look at it on the update of my question.